# Meteor Cordova app: Android crash

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

My app started crashing on my Android device. It used to work well and I did not change anything... I think it is related to Cordova but I have no clue why it suddenly started to crash.

Here is the log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.meteor.webapp.AssetBundle.getVersion()' on a null object reference
    at com.meteor.webapp.WebAppLocalServer.onReset(WebAppLocalServer.java:186)
    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.onReset(PluginManager.java:465)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl$EngineClient.onPageStarted(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewClient.onPageStarted(SystemWebViewClient.java:145)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageStarted(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:531)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:157)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide more information, like what you changed just prior to this crash, what you have tried to do to remedy it. You could also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how your question stacks up to the standard

Comment: Hello Mikkel, problem is that I did not change anything and it used to work pretty well. I think it is related to Cordova...

Comment: I removed and reinstalled the app and it is working now. Yet, I do not understand what is this bug and how to prevent it from happening to other users...